# how get result of php class in URL Address

Tags: php, class, converters, currency

i want use this currency conversion php class :

http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/php-currency-conversion-exchange-rates-xml/

But i've absolutely need to obtain the result of the conversion in URL Address, same as this:

```
http://www.example.com/converter/converter.php?100USD&=76EUR
```

Do you think it's this possible ?

So, could you give me an example !

actually, i make this but, i'm not satisfy with this :

```
<?php
include('CurrencyConverter.php');
$x = new CurrencyConverter('your_host','your_username','your_password','your_database_name','your_table_name');
echo $x->convert($_REQUEST['amount'],$_REQUEST['from'],$_REQUEST['to']);
?>
```

PS: The result i would obtain is :
http://www.my_url.com/converter.php?=100USD=76EUR

Comment: No news! Nobody for help me?

Answer (score 0):

OFC it is possible, you just have invalid url.

Instead of:

> http://www.myurl.com/converter/converter.php**?100USD&=76EUR**

use:

> http://www.myurl.com/converter/converter.php**?amount=100&from=USD&to=EUR**

Comment: Yes, i understand this ! i need an url formatted like this 

amount&=from&=?to